# Qt: QAbstractItemModel became slow if I emit layoutChanged()

Tags: c++, performance, qt, qml, qabstractitemmodel

I subclassed from QAbstractItemModel and made model that using at TableView in QML.

I'm trying to remove item.

```
bool DownloadListModel::removeDownloadById(const QString &id)
{
    DownloadFile* download = getDownloadById(id);
    int index = getDownloadIndex(download);
    if (download) {
        beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(),index,index);

        _downloadsList.removeOne(download);
        _downloadsMap.remove(id);
        download->deleteLater();

        _db->deleteDownload(id);

        endRemoveRows();

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It's working good except one bug: when I select item in table after deleting, table highlights wrong item. So, I'm trying to emit layoutChanged() signal:

```
bool DownloadListModel::removeDownloadById(const QString &id)
{
    DownloadFile* download = getDownloadById(id);
    int index = getDownloadIndex(download);
    if (download) {
        emit layoutAboutToBeChanged();
        beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(),index,index);

        _downloadsList.removeOne(download);
        _downloadsMap.remove(id);
        download->deleteLater();

        _db->deleteDownload(id);

        endRemoveRows();
        emit layoutChanged();

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now it works good, but very slow. What's wrong? How to do it correct?

There is QML code:

```
SortFilterProxyModel {
                    id: searchFilterProxyModel
                    source: downloadsModel //downloadsModel.count > 0 ? downloadsModel : null //FIXME:

                    sortOrder: tableView.sortIndicatorOrder
                    sortCaseSensitivity: Qt.CaseInsensitive
                    sortRole: downloadsModel.downloadsCount > 0 ? tableView.getColumn(tableView.sortIndicatorColumn).role : ""

                    filterString: ""//"*" + searchTextInput.text + "*"
                    filterSyntax: SortFilterProxyModel.Wildcard
                    filterCaseSensitivity: Qt.CaseInsensitive
                    dynamicSortFilter: false
                }

                SortFilterProxyModel {
                    id: tagsProxyModel
                    source: searchFilterProxyModel

                    filterString: categoryView.searchString
                    filterSyntax: SortFilterProxyModel.RegExp
                    filterCaseSensitivity: Qt.CaseInsensitive
                    filterRole: "downloadTagNames"
                    dynamicSortFilter: false
                }

                Item {
                    id: main
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    ColumnLayout {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        TableView {
                            //TODO: implement better column sizes
                            id: tableView
                            sortIndicatorVisible : true //TODO: implement sorting
                            Layout.fillWidth: true
                            Layout.fillHeight: true
                            model: tagsProxyModel
                            onDoubleClicked: {
                                expandingPanel.pressButton()
                            }

                            TableViewColumn {
                                movable: false
                                resizable: false
                                width: 5
                                role: tableView.currentRow
                                delegate: Item {

                                }
                            }

                            TableViewColumn {
                                movable: false
                                resizable: false
                                width: 13 //NOTE: not very good
                                role: "downloadTagsList"
                                delegate: Image {
                                    id: fileIcon
                                    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                                    source: "qrc:/img/icon-file.png" //TODO: another icons
                                    width: sourceSize.width
                                    height: sourceSize.height
                                    MouseArea {
                                        anchors.fill: parent
                                        onClicked: {
                                            console.log(styleData.selected);
                                            tableView.itemDelegate.visible=false;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            TableViewColumn {
                                role: "downloadFileName";
                                resizable: false
                                title: "File name";
                                width: tableView.width-525
                            }
                            TableViewColumn {
                                role: "downloadHumanReadableSize";
                                resizable: false
                                title: "Size";
                                width: 80
                            }
                            TableViewColumn {
                                id: downloadStateColumn
                                role: "downloadState"
                                title: "Status"
                                width: 80
                                resizable: false
                            }
                            TableViewColumn {
                                role: "downloadTimeRemaining"; //TODO: implement time remaining property
                                title: "Time remaining";
                                width: 140
                                resizable: false
                            }
                            TableViewColumn {
                                id: progressControlColumn
                                role: "downloadPercentage";
                                title: "Progress";
                                width: 200
                                resizable: false
                                delegate: ProgressControlItem {
                                    id: progressControlItem
                                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                                    showPercentageNumbers: true
                                    progressState: tagsProxyModel.get(styleData.row).downloadState
                                    progressPercentage: parseInt(tagsProxyModel.get(styleData.row).downloadPercentage)

                                    itemId: tagsProxyModel.get(styleData.row).id

                                    Connections {
                                        target: styleData

                                        onValueChanged: {
                                            progressPercentage = parseInt(styleData.value)
                                            if (progressState != tagsProxyModel.get(styleData.row).downloadState)
                                                progressState = tagsProxyModel.get(styleData.row).downloadState
                                        }
                                    }

                                    onOpenClicked: {
                                        Qt.openUrlExternally("file://"+tagsProxyModel.get(styleData.row).downloadLocation) //TODO: get rid of code dublication
                                    }
                                    onResumeClicked: {
                                        tagsProxyModel.setDataAt(styleData.row,"active","downloadState")
                                    }
                                    onPauseClicked: {
                                        tagsProxyModel.setDataAt(styleData.row,"paused","downloadState")
                                    }
                                    onStopClicked: {
                                        tagsProxyModel.setDataAt(styleData.row,"stopped","downloadState")
                                    }
                                    onRestartClicked: {
                                        tagsProxyModel.setDataAt(styleData.row,"","downloadState")
                                    }

                                    /*Connections {
                                        target: downloadsModel

                                        onDataChanged: {

                                                console.log("data changed: " + tagsProxyModel.get(topLeft).downloadUrl)
                                        }
                                    }*/
                                }
                            }
//                            onCurrentRowChanged: {
//                                fileInfoExpander.sourceItemChanged()
//                            }
                            style: TableViewCustomStyle {
                                headerDelegateHeight: 30
                                rowDelegateHeight: 30
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: It is hard to say something about QML. `layoutChanged` method is slow, because it force recalculation of all items geometry. It is strange, could you provide some QML code?

Comment: I wonder what happens if the underlying model is based on a vector that reallocates?

Comment: @DmitrySazonov attached QML code